# React? What alternatives to do with data

Tags: reactjs, api, store

Good day, i have a question. What alternatives you can do with data from React.

If you have:

1. One Placeholder with mail (code you can see below)
2. Form with 4 steps(every steps have 2 variables.

What you think? Good idea is implementing backend + database or send this data to store?

```
class Mail extends React.Component{

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={value:''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit= this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

        handleChange(event){
          this.setState({value:event.target.value});
        }
        handleSubmit(event){
          console.log('submited');
        }


      render(){
        return(
        <form onSubmit ={this.handleSubmit}
            className ="mail_ebook">
           <div className="group mail_left">
             <input className ="text" type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
             required/>
             <span className="highlight"></span>
             <span className="bar"></span>
             <label>write your mail now</label>
           </div>
              <input className ="hero_button margin_left" type="submit" value="Read it" />
        </form>
      )
    }
    };
```

Comment: Right now the input value is saved into your state. So your Mail m has m.state.value == whatever you put into input.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to create a collection of all such values? Do you want to save to file? If you want a state manager I suggest looking into Redux JS.

Comment: Yes, i reading about Redux. If i save this data to store, how can i later check all saved data? And where it will save?

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OP request (see comments) I will recommend using ReduxJS.
With Redux the core concept to understand is Reducers, **pure functions** which will have a default state and can be dispatched actions with dispatch(action). Upon elaborating an action, they will update the state. You can define your set of actions (for example one to add an input variable, one to delete the last added or by name.. just examples) and the state will change according to each action. The reducer will then return the current state, a Javascript object. You can retrieve the state with getState() as well.

Please read https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#getState

If your question also includes wanting to save this data to a database you will have to use some API to connect to it, or perhaps fs to save to files.